# How to loop through 1D array elements multiple times?

Tags: matlab, octave

Assuming `size_of_array < n`, to iterate through array elements multiple times, normally I would use something like (in C++):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    elem = arr[ i % size_of_arr ];
}
```

If `arr = {1, 2, 3};`, for `elem` I would get:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 ...
```

However, in MATLAB / Octave indexes start from `1` and:

```
for i = 1 : n

  elem = arr( mod( i, length(arr) + 1) );
end
```

so when `n == length(arr)` I get an error:

> error: arr(0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals

How is this done when indexes start from 1?

Comment: The idiomatic form for that is `mod(i-1,n)+1` (I call it _1-based modulus_). So, perhaps `elem = arr(mod(i-1, length(arr))+1);` works for you (I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: never use `length`, it returns the length of the longest dimension. Instead, use `numel` (number of elements).

Comment: `error: arr(0): ` The zero is what Matlab is trying to yell at you about.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the helpful comment, it worked perfectly. If you are interested for the use, check : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174876/iterative-implementation-of-towers-of-hanoi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c++ you would do

```cpp
arr[ i % size_of_arr]
```

where the inner index `i % size_of_arr` is in range `[0 size_of_arr-1]`

In MATLAB, `i` is in range `[1 size_of_arr]`, thus just change to

```
mod( i-1, numel(arr) ) + 1
```

the first bit (`mod( i-1, numel(arr))`) makes sure that the index is inside `[0 size_of_arr-1]`, and the you just need to add 1 to that.

Comment: Thank you! So, what we do is offsetting the index to zero-origin and adjusting the result of modulo operation to start from 1 and on, right?